# DataServiceQuery

Tags: silverlight, ado.net, wcf-data-services

Is there a GetTable or similar method on The ado.net dataserviceContext object in silverlight. I need to write a generic query builder to aid my silverlight LOB app. This could carve the workload in half.

I already use expression trees passed in from Lambdas for the Where clause, it would just be could to be able to specify the entity which I am working with.